# Проверка SQL запросов на логическую корректность

Tags: sql, валидация, linter

Есть проблема, требуется проверять в "автомате" корректность SQL запросов. Часто случается получать единый файл с 100+ строк скриптом на обновление данных в котором есть **логическая** ошибка

к примеру в файле есть строка

```sql
UPDATE client
SET FIRSTNAME = 'Татьяна';
```

Такую подставу-строку не факт, что заметишь особенно в длинном файле...

Может кто знает какое решение для валидации и передачи запроса от разработчика скрипта сопровожденцу или просто консольную утилиту

Comment: datagrip от jetbrains он конечно платный, но поверьте оно того стоит

Comment: хочется какую-то утилиту что бы встроить в CI/CD, подсказки IDE хороши, но их могут отключить проигнорировать и тд

Comment: Синтаксически приведённая строка запроса - корректна. А вот насчёт логического контроля... по-моему, проще наладить бэкапы.